# how do we authorize jwt token if it has 9000 kb length?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ncqrs

We have jwt token which has 9000kb length and this size is more then our server size. so we are unable to authorized it. how can we fix this issue.

We were trying to separate header and claims then authorize them. But could not find any solution.

Comment: Did all the information is needed to store into the user claim? If you want to store some data at client side, I suggest you could consider using the local storage.

Comment: yes , all information is needed to store in the user claims

Comment: You should consider not put all the information inside the claims to avoid this thing. Or you could put part of the claims inside the cookie and then query and add left claims in the server during the authentication.

Comment: all information are useful in claims we can't avoid

Comment: OK As I told before, you could store part of claim when the user login in and then add the claim when the user login in.

Answer (score 0):

Woah! 9000kb is huuuge!!. The maximum operational limit on most of the webserver is 8k more on this [here](https://8K%20on%20the%20majority%20of%20current%20servers). Ask yourself:

1. What information is contained within the JWT token?
2. Is all the information necessary for authorization and user identification?
3. Can any of the information be stored elsewhere and referenced within the token?
4. Are there any redundant or unnecessary data fields that can be removed?

You can split the entire jwt into multiple jwts and verify each of them but it is still not feasible considering you have 9mb of token.

Comment: thanks, Is it possible , if we splits header and claim then authorize them?

Comment: Because there is no redundant  and if we store the information in somewhere but still we need to verified them and then it will take the same size again.

Comment: You can refer a jwt inside a jwt. For ex. You can use a location like this `{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "token_location": "https://example.com/other_jwt"
}`